# Aw snap Chromium error even after clearing cache Ubuntu

Tags: html, google-chrome, chromium, ubuntu-14.04

I have a website http://kounj.web44.net whick works fine in all browsers.This week i noticed that my site would throw an "Aw,Snap " error on Chromium(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit).
I deleted every user but the problem remains.In other browser is working fine.Any ideas

Note.The problem appeared after upgrading my chromium browser to the latest version
UPDATE:
The problem was caused by a script for flare app and was resolved by removing the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the users

Try restoring chrome to its default. This can be done in the settings options

Comment: Oh then Sorry might be a bug